# Show that $\mu(A\setminus B)=0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $B\subset{A}$ and $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$. Prove that $\mu(A\setminus B)=0.$

If we have $\mu(A)<\infty$ then $\mu(A\setminus B)=\mu(A)-\mu(B)=0$.

But $\mu(A)=\infty$, I can't prove $\mu(A\setminus B)=0$.

Comment: It's not true if $\mu(A)=\infty$. For example, $A=[0,\infty)$ and $B=[1,\infty)$.

Comment: I'm proving a theorem in regard to this problem. Thank you, I should review it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true if $\mu(A)=\infty$. For example, $A=[0,+\infty)$ and $B=[1,+\infty)$ gives $\mu(A\setminus B)=1$.

Or $A=\mathbb R$ and $B=[0,+\infty)$ gives $\mu(A\setminus B)=\infty$.